# Counting probability problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

New to probability I am getting stuck on this counting problem

Assuming two numbers are selected at random from a black box with replacement from the integer set $\{1, 2, . . . , n\}$ and let $K$ be the maximum of the two numbers. Find $E[K]$.

So far I have

Thus $P(K=1)=1/n^2$  & $P(K=n)=(2n−1)/n^2$
But I can't seem to work out the expectation as the set is not limited (goes to $n$)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative route:
$$\mathbb EK=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} P(K>k)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} [1-P(K\leq k)]=n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} P(K\leq k)$$
Here $P(K\leq k)=(\frac{k}{n})^2$

Answer (score 0):

$E_n(K)=\sum_{r=1}^{r=n} \frac {r(2r-1)}{n^2}$

You want an expression for $E_n$ in terms of n.

$E_n(K)=\frac 1 {n^2} \sum (2r^2-r)$

$=\frac 1 {n^2} [2\sum r^2 - \sum r]$

You an use standard sums to get the rest...

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the probability of each value:

- The probability of $1$ is $\frac{1}{n^2}$
- The probability of $2$ is $\frac{3}{n^2}$
- The probability of $3$ is $\frac{5}{n^2}$
- ...
- The probability of $n$ is $\frac{2n-1}{n^2}$

So the expected value is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k(2k-1)}{n^2}=\frac{4n^2+3n-1}{6n}$